Creating a PurchaseInvoiceLines with a UnitOfMeasure through Business Centrals API fails
So I am trying to create the following purchase invoice line
{
  "itemId":"be04fb82-fdaa-ee11-a568-0022489c7d90",
  "quantity":152.0,
  "expectedReceiptDate":"0001-01-01", 
  "description":"External number Solgt af Firstname Lastname",
  "unitOfMeasureId":"01e0edc8-2022-ed11-90eb-000d3ade9914"
}

Where I try to create a line with the following unit (from a GET request):
{
  "@odata.etag": "W/\"JzIwOzEyOTI4MTAyNzc4MjEyNDI3MDQwMTswMDsn\"",
  "id": "01e0edc8-2022-ed11-90eb-000d3ade9914",
  "code": "KG",
  "displayName": "Kilo",
  "internationalStandardCode": "KGM",
  "symbol": "",
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2022-08-22T13:47:22.113Z"
},

Which I can without the unitOfMeasureId. But with it, or with unitOfMeasureCode set to KG (or both) I get a 404 response and the following message:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Internal_InvalidTableRelation",
    "message": "The field Unit of Measure Code of table Purch. Inv. Line Aggregate contains a value (KG) that cannot be found in the related table (Item Unit of Measure).  CorrelationId:  9feff4b3-9595-4a2e-847d-9f314a0bec35."
  }
}

The message is the same with or without unitOfMeasureCode set. And it's the same if I only set unitOfMeasureCode.
Is it because I have to use the same unit as the items baseUnitOfMeasure?

The error states that the given unit of measure "KG" is not available for this item. Please make sure that "KG" is setup in the Item Card as a Item Unit of Measure (not only as a Unit of Measure).
I have been able to create a sales invoice line with a unit of measure code that isn't the base unit of measure with the following POST request:
{
  "lineType": "Item",
  "lineObjectNumber": "10000",
  "description": "Test",
  "unitOfMeasureId": "084b70e8-6430-ed11-97e8-000d3a83c9c1",
  "unitPrice": 54.9,
  "quantity": 3
}

084b70e8-6430-ed11-97e8-000d3a83c9c1 is the ID for a unit of measure, that is setup for the item 10000 on my business central instance.
I didn't find a way to create the Item Unit of Measure entries without a custom api.

I am not seeing a Document No. in your request body. We typically create the Header, and then insert the lines.
The order of the fields is very particular with Business Central APIs. You could try moving the unit of measure above your quantity; that's how I have it in my APIs, and @dannoe does as well.
